# How does recursion work in the below program?

Tags: recursion

```
/* Head ends here */
void quickSort(int ar_size, int *  ar) 
{
  int i, j, t;
  int pivot = 0;
  if((ar_size == 0) || (ar_size == 1)) 
  {
    return;
  }

  int A[1000], B[1000], s1 = 0, s2 = 0;
  for(i = 1; i < ar_size; i++)
  {
    if(ar[i] <= ar[pivot]) 
    {
      A[s1++] = ar[i];
    }
    else 
    {
      B[s2++] = ar[i];
    }
  }

  quickSort(s1, A);
  quickSort(s2, B);

  t = ar[pivot];

  for(i = 0; i < s1; i++) 
  {
    ar[i] = A[i];
  }
  ar[i] = t;

  for(i = 0; i < s2; i++)
  {
    ar[s1 + i +1] = B[i];
  }

  for(i = 0; i< ar_size; i++)
  {
    printf("%d ", ar[i]);
  }

  printf("\n");
}

/* Tail starts here */
int main() 
{
  int _ar_size;

  scanf("%d", &_ar_size);

  int _ar[_ar_size], _ar_i;

  for(_ar_i = 0; _ar_i < _ar_size; _ar_i++) 
  { 
    scanf("%d", &_ar[_ar_i]); 
  }

  quickSort(_ar_size, _ar);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, mark your code and click `Ctrl + K` to format it correctly.

Comment: Which language is that?

Comment: @Biffen `scanf("%d", &_ar[_ar_i]);` It is C or C++ probably

Comment: @TheCrafter Yeah, that's my guess too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to understand how quicksort works. I suggest you take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNB5JCG3vts).

Now about recursion. The idea is simple. You have a function that does something specific but in the process it calls itself. A fine example is the factorial of a number.

```
int factorial(int x)
{
    if(x = 0)
        return 1;

    return x * factorial(x - 1);
}
```

So if I call `factorial(4);` I will get
`factorial(4)`= `4 * factorial(3)`= `4 * 3 * factorial(2)` = `4 * 3 * 2 * factorial(1)` = `4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * factorial(0)` = `4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1` = `24`

Comment: for the input 5,8,1,3,7,9,2  please explain me how its working

Comment: Watch the video I told you. It explains everything perfect.